# Nestjs Can't Install @t00nday/nestjs-pdf

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I was try to install @t00nday/nestjs-pdf using npm, But found error like this

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: server-nestjs@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @nestjs/common@9.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/common
npm ERR!   @nestjs/common@"^9.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @nestjs/common@"^6.10.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @t00nday/nestjs-pdf@3.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@t00nday/nestjs-pdf
npm ERR!   @t00nday/nestjs-pdf@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

I dont want to use command `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`.
I want to try downgrading my nest version but too much peer dependency to change in package.json
Anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`@t00nday/nestjs-pdf` has a peer dependency on `@nestjs/common` for verion `^6.0.0`, `^7.0.0` or `^8.0.0`. This means that any `@nestjs/common` version 6, 7, or 8 compatible version van be installed. By Semver's standards, compatible means non-major version difference (there's more nuance than that but it's enough to think of that for this use case). In your application you have `@nestjs/common@9.2.1` installed, which npm reads as non-compatible due to the major difference in the versions.

In reality, Nest version 9 *should* be compatible with version 8, so you can use `--force` to get around this if you need. The other option is to drop all of your Nest dependencies down to v8 compatible versions, **or** fork `@t00nday/nestjs-pdf` and publish a Nest v9 compatible version or make a PR to update that library for the author and hope it gets merged and published quickly.

Comment: If using --force when install in my local. Should i modified my command when run npm install in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Your docker install should mimic your local install. Or actually, it should be the other way around. Local should mimic docker.